# for loop with ode45 solver

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

i have a question about using ode45 solver.
here is my equation and functions:
[image: main equation(-s)]
[image: and functions]

here you can pick arbitrary to unknown variables like $\sigma^{2}_{E}$.
I want to write this system and solve it by ode45.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this as frame:

```
function dydt = prime(t,y)
    f = reshape(y,[m,n])
    // compute constants and intermediate values
    dfdt = ...
    dydt = reshape(dfdt,[m*n,1]) 
end
```

so externally, you deal with a flat vector while internally you can use the matrix structure resp. indexing with two indices.